# Disable or enable Show/hide columns in jqgrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have a datagrid in my page which is built using jqgrid. Here, I would like to disable an option called "Show/hide Columns" to my grid. Is there any way, so that I can disable/enable it by just adding an attribute and passing it a value (i.e. true/false in this case). It would be a great help, if someone look into this and help.

Thanks,
Santosh.

Comment: please include relevant code like html and js

Comment: Got the solution, thanks for the help. @Pekka

Comment: You should change **tags** used in question. If you use **DataGrid** instead of **jqGrid** then you should use the corresponding tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, I have a Wrapper js called DataGrid.js on top of jqgrid library. Which contains all the functionalities. I have a function named "addChooseColumnsButton" and it adds the icon on my grid to Show/hide columns. You can see the function below.

```
DataGrid.prototype.addChooseColumnsButton = function() {

if (this.options.choose) {
    var me = this;
    this.grid.navButtonAdd(this.options.pager, {
        id: 'choose_cols_nav_btn',
        caption: '',
        buttonicon: 'ui-icon-calculator',
        title: 'Show/Hide columns',
        position: 'last',
        onClickButton: function() {
            me.chooseColumnsAction();
        }
    });
}
```

};

To disable the same on my grid, I have written my grid tag as below with attribute "choose" as false.

This "choose" is taken from "if (this.options.choose)" from my function. It solves my problem.

Note: to avoid calling a function from our library we can take the "options" name and make it "false". In this case, "this.options.choose" I picked choose and made false to avoid calling this function.

Comment: What product you use? The method `chooseColumnsAction` and `DataGrid` not exist in jqGrid. If all the objects and methods are *your custom method and objects* then one can ask which value for other readers have such code?

Comment: Yeah Oleg, these all are customized methods and js file on top of jqgrid library. Just would like to inform that, a function which is there in the jqgrid library can be avoided from calling by using the above approach. @Oleg